# How to repeat each test with a delay if a particular Exception happens (pytest)

Tags: pytest

I have a load of test which I want to rerun if there is a particular exception. The reason for this is that I am running real API calls to a server and sometimes I hit the rate limit for the API, in which case I want to wait and try again.

However, I am also using a pytest fixture to make each test is run several times, because I am sending requests to different servers (the actual use case is different cryptocurrency exchanges).

Using pytest-rerunfailures comes very close to what I need...apart from that I can't see how to look at the exception of the last test run in the condition.

Below is some code which shows what I am trying to achieve, but I don't want to write code like this for every test obviously.

```
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(
    params=EXCHANGE_NAMES,
)
async def client(request):
    exchange_name = request.param
    exchange_client = get_exchange_client(exchange_name)
    return exchange_client


def test_something(client):
    test_something.count += 1
    ### This block is the code I want to
    try:
        result = client.do_something()
    except RateLimitException:
        test_something.count
        if test_something.count <= 3:
            sleep_duration = get_sleep_duration(client)
            time.sleep(sleep_duration)
            # run the same test again
            test_something()
        else:
            raise
    expected = [1,2,3]

    assert result == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [retry library](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) to wrap your actual code in:

```
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(
    params=EXCHANGE_NAMES,
    autouse=True,
)
async def client(request):
    exchange_name = request.param
    exchange_client = get_exchange_client(exchange_name)
    return exchange_client


def test_something(client):
    actual_test_something(client)


@retry(RateLimitException, tries=3, delay=2)
def actual_test_something(client):
    '''Retry on RateLimitException, raise error after 3 attempts, sleep 2 seconds between attempts.'''

    result = client.do_something()
    expected = [1,2,3]

    assert result == expected
```

The code looks much cleaner this way.

Comment: This looks nice, but I need to get the delay dynamically depending on which client is being used. I've managed to fork and change the pytest-rerunfailures plugin to do this now so that a delay expression can be used which has access to the function params and globals, and the previous exception, and the condition has access to the same. Although it probably would have been better for me to do that for the retry package instead since it handles an exception already so looks neater